# Email Notifications in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using a repository setup in Laravel 5.1 and I want to start using events to handle email notifications.

Where would I place my command to fire off email notifications? Do they go in the controller, repository?

If anybody could shed some light on the best practices this would be great.

I already know that I can use the queue manager so that's not a problem.

Comment: is your repository being called from the controller or another job handler?

Comment: I wouldn't call the repository from the controller. I would instead create a job and call the repository from the handler method. After that I would then fire off the event. Try to keep everything as abstract away from the framework as possible

Comment: Look at this link you might get useful info regarding your question http://www.amitavroy.com/justread/content/articles/events-laravel-5-and-customize-model-save

Comment: I would say it would depend what email notifications you want and when. I have used a cron job to send out emails for reminders and have also sent emails through the controller to admins. I've also seen email being sent through the routes. View http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail for some ideas.